# How to call a stored procedure inside another stored procedure when the if condition satisfies

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have ran in to an issue when calling 2 stored procedures within another stored procedure in Snowflake. The below is my requirement

`if ((to_number((to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'dd')))=10))  then we need to call sp name edw.bison_details`

And everyday if the above condition is satisfied or not, `eds.bison_delta_details` stored procedure needs to run with the main stored procedure.

Can anybody help me with that?

*Updated...*

I have wrote a calling code in snowflake. but its giving an error like,

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'if'.

This is the code that leads to the error message when calling a sp within another sp in snowflake.

```
if ((to_number((to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'dd')))==5))
CALL STG.BISON_LAND_DATA('`+ID+`'::VARCHAR,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ::VARCHAR,
'{"name": "`+name+`","task_name": "`+task_name+`","sp": "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA","up_date": "`+upd_date+`","date": "`+date+`","id": "`+ID+`"}'::VARCHAR)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute stored procedure inside another stored procedure in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63515722/execute-stored-procedure-inside-another-stored-procedure-in-snowflake)

Comment: Hello @DigvijayS , this is not what I need. Thanks for the reply...

Comment: Please can you explain in more detail why the answer given by @digvijayS is not what you need? Can you provide the code you have written and explain why it doesn't achieve what you want?

Comment: Yes..  This is the code that leads to the error message when calling a sp within another sp in snowflake.

    if ((to_number((to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'dd')))==5))
    CALL STG.BISON_LAND_DATA('`+ID+`'::VARCHAR,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ::VARCHAR,
    '{"name": "`+name+`","task_name": "`+task_name+`","sp": "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA","up_date": "`+upd_date+`","date": "`+date+`","id": "`+ID+`"}'::VARCHAR)

hOW TO FIX THIS ISSUE?

Comment: Is this code meant to be javascript - because if so, then it’s nowhere close to being valid code?

Answer (score 1):

`to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'dd')` gives you day of month but simpler would be to use `DAYOFMONTH` thus the first line can become:

```
if( DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) == 5 ) {
    ...
}
```

and your stored procedure call can be pulled apart to see what makes sense and doesn't like:

```
var parm1 = '`+ID+`'::VARCHAR;
var parm2 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ::VARCHAR;
var json_str = '{"name": "`+name+`","task_name": "`+task_name+`","sp": "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA","up_date": "`+upd_date+`","date": "`+date+`","id": "`+ID+`"}'::VARCHAR;
CALL STG.BISON_LAND_DATA(parm1, parm2, json_str);
```

in the context of the code shown, it doesn't make sense to use all three quote styles, given we are starting the strings with `'` quotes, to break them to do string concatenation you could just use a normal single quote again.

```
var json_str = '{"name": "'+ name +'","task_name": "'+ task_name +'","sp": "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA","up_date": "'+ upd_date +'","date": "'+ date +'","id": "'+ ID +'"}'::VARCHAR;
```

`parm1` is just an toString() thus could be

```
var parm1 = ID.toString();
```

`json_str` is a string representing json object, given you are in JavaScript, you could just create the object, and then toString() that.. thus it all becomes:

```
if( DAYOFMONTH( CURRENT_DATE ) == 5 ) {
    var parm1 = ID.toString();
    var parm2 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ::VARCHAR;
    var json_obj = {name: name, task_name: task_name, sp: "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA", up_date: upd_date, date: date, id: ID };
    CALL STG.BISON_LAND_DATA(parm1, parm2, json_obj.toString());
}
```

And given your question about then actually code that you are correct, and copying the logic from the linked question on [Execute stored procedure inside another stored procedure in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63515722/execute-stored-procedure-inside-another-stored-procedure-in-snowflake) and doc's on [working with Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#recursive-stored-procedure-example) together:

it should become:

```
if( DAYOFMONTH( CURRENT_DATE ) == 5 ) {
    var parm1 = ID.toString();
    var parm2 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ::VARCHAR;
    var json_obj = {name: name, task_name: task_name, sp: "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA", up_date: upd_date, date: date, id: ID };

    var cmd = "CALL STG.BISON_LAND_DATA(:1, :2, :3)";
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
          {
          sqlText: cmd,
          binds: [parm1, parm2, json_obj.toString()]
          }
          );
    var result1 = stmt.execute();
    result1 .next();    
    var val = result1.doSomeThingWithResults...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After we doing this, do we need to run execute command? such as 
 executeStatement('', call, []) ?