# SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'if'. - Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is the code that leads to the error message when calling a Stored Procedure within another Stored Procedure in snowflake.

```
if ((to_number((to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'dd')))==5))
CALL STG.BISON_LAND_DATA('`+ID+`'::VARCHAR,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ::VARCHAR,
'{"name": "`+name+`","task_name": "`+task_name+`","sp": "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA","up_date": "`+upd_date+`","date": "`+date+`","id": "`+ID+`"}'::VARCHAR)
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Why have you created another question that duplicates your previous question?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate answer to the [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70556812/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-inside-another-stored-procedure-when-the-if-condi/70560276#70560276):

`to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'dd')` gives you day of month but simpler would be to use [DAYOFMONTH](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/year.html#syntax) thus the first line can become:

```
if( DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE) == 5 ) {
    ...
}
```

or you could use `DATE_PART(day, CURRENT_DATE) == 5`

and your stored procedure call can be pulled apart to see what makes sense and doesn't like:

```
var parm1 = '`+ID+`'::VARCHAR;
var parm2 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ::VARCHAR;
var json_str = '{"name": "`+name+`","task_name": "`+task_name+`","sp": "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA","up_date": "`+upd_date+`","date": "`+date+`","id": "`+ID+`"}'::VARCHAR;
CALL STG.BISON_LAND_DATA(parm1, parm2, json_str);
```

In the context of the code shown, it doesn't make sense to use all three quote styles, given we are starting the strings with `'` quotes, to break them to do string concatenation you could just use a normal single quote again.

```
var json_str = '{"name": "'+ name +'","task_name": "'+ task_name +'","sp": "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA","up_date": "'+ upd_date +'","date": "'+ date +'","id": "'+ ID +'"}'::VARCHAR;
```

`parm1` is just an toString() thus could be

```
var parm1 = ID.toString();
```

`json_str` is a string representing json object, given you are in JavaScript, you could just create the object, and then toString() that.. thus it all becomes:

```
if( DAYOFMONTH( CURRENT_DATE ) == 5 ) {
    var parm1 = ID.toString();
    var parm2 = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ::VARCHAR;
    var json_obj = {name: name, task_name: task_name, sp: "STG.BISON_LAND_DATA", up_date: upd_date, date: date, id: ID };
    CALL STG.BISON_LAND_DATA(parm1, parm2, json_obj.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the best at SQL or any of that, but I think the statements in the if should be in braces (`{}`).